# MongoDB PrivateLink not working: Connection timed out

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas

So, I'm trying to set up a MongoDB PrivateLink to my AWS EKS but it seems like my pod is not managing to connect.

I followed this guide https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/connecting-applications-securely-to-a-mongodb-atlas-data-plane-with-aws-privatelink/

and set up the following materials:

- Created a new VPC with 3 availability zones
- Created EKS and attached it to the VPC (the EKS has Private + Public networking enabled)
- I used the private subnets for composing the VPC under the MongoDB privateLink and used the VPC name of my newly created VPC
- Afterwards i ran the command that mongodb shows and waited for it to create.
- It shows "Available" under "Endpoint Status" and "Ready for connection requests" under endpoint service status
- I use my correct username/password and the mongo URI is correct (I whitelisted my computer and tested and it worked)

I'm rather new to the AWS - PrivateLink setup and don't seem to get it working. Should i perhaps use the public subnet ids? What could be the issue?

Comment: That tutorial looks incomplete to me. For example they don't mention configuring the private link security group, unless I'm missing something. I'd look at this documentation: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-private-endpoint/ which also includes some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288962/how-to-establish-peering-between-mongodb-atlas-and-google-app-engine-standard-en/65296831#65296831 and linked answers.

Comment: Thanks, indeed adding the security group worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unrelated, since the topic referenced doesn't mention PrivateLink, but rather "Peering". So can you know that a resolution for "Peering" would fix a PrivateLink issue?

Comment: @Maxim Could you kindly outline the steps you needed to make? I have the same problem, but the trouble shooting tips from MongoDB are kind of sparse. I don't understand them / wish there was something more detailed to follow along