# Lambda not connecting to Mongodb via privatelink

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mongodb-.net-driver, aws-private-link

I have deployed via terraform a setup with lambdas, mongodb cluster, aws vpc and a privatelink endpoint and my connection string isn't working. i am getting a timeout error from mongo.

My connection string is:
"mongodb+srv://:@XXXXXXXXXXXX-pl-0.XXXXX.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

I was wondering if it could be to do with security, maybe the ports i'm allowing are wrong, can someone advise what they should be?

Any ideas on why this isn't the connecting?

Comment: It's unclear how you expect people to comment or troubleshoot your setup without sharing the relevant aspect of it's configuration. Nonetheless, a likely cause could be that your Lambda is not running within your vpc so does not have access to the endpoint or that security groups are preventing connectivity. Share the relevant config if you want more detailed help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288962/how-to-establish-peering-between-mongodb-atlas-and-google-app-engine-standard-en/65296831#65296831