# Mongodb atlas dedicated cluster: how to create peering connection with AWS and then access the cluster without whitelisting ips

Tags: mongodb, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas

We have a dedicated M10 cluster in Mongodb Atlas, on which I have created a peering connection with AWS to incorporate security using VPC. I have followed this Mongodb document for configuring peering connection between AWS and cluster.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/

The peering connection is created successfully and is active now. But the thing is, I am unable to connect to cluster without whitelisting my IP. When I try to connect without whitelisting the IP, it gives below error:

> Something went wrong MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect
> to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is
> that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't
> whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas
> cluster's IP whitelist:
> https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

While after whitelisting the IP, I am able to connect to cluster successfully from local environment.
What do I need to access a cluster within VPC using application? I can not use the option IP whitelisting as every user's IP can not be whitelisted.

I have already whitelisted CIDR block as mentioned by the above documentation.

Comment: VPC peering is to connect to to Atlas from AWS VPC (EC2, Lambda, etc). There is no magic in peering, it's essentially the same whitelisting but for the private range of IPs (VPC CIDR or subnet) assigned to the peer VPC. Peering changes nothing in terms of accessing Atlas from any external IP, e.g. your laptop or PC.

Comment: What does the last sentence have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: @D.SM I got confused with network peering and IP whitelisting. That's why added the last sentence that following the steps provided in the document have whitelisted CIDR block as well.

Comment: @AlexBlex I tried connecting to cluster with Lambda with the peering connection created and Lambda lies within the same VPC, which is the accepter VPC. But I couldn't connect to it without allowing access from anywhere i.e. 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: It's hard to advise anything without details of your set up. If it doesn't work you probably missed something, made a typo, or hit a genuine bug. Please check https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda and related documentation.

Comment: If I speculate I'd say it must be the routing table. The symptoms look like traffic leaves private range and goes through the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP whitelisting is separate from peering. Peering determines the network, whitelisting determines who on the network is allowed access.

If you want to allow access from anything that has physical connectivity to the database, whitelist the entire world (0.0.0.0/0).

Comment: Can you help me with this? If I want to connect it using lambda then I will require peering, right? (If I have not mistaken what you said). But, I am unable to connect to it using lambda after creating a peering connection.

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945739/mongodb-and-google-cloud-functions-vpc-peering/64950407#64950407 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276291/cannot-connect-to-mongo-atlas-using-vpc-peering-from-gcp-cluster/62276778#62276778 for peering and general ip whitelisting strategy. I don't know if you need peering for lambdas, my suspicion is it's not required.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda looks quite useful too.